# How to delete an object in a list properly?

Tags: c++, list

Here is my list

```
list<DisplayableObject> objects;
```

I want to put new displayable objects in it

I want a function to be able to just completely free the list and delete it

I've seen erase, clear etc but when I read online people say I need to explicitly do it as those class functions will not actually free the memory?

I've made a few approaches and no idea if they are correct:

```
iter = objects.begin();
```

1

```
while (!objects.empty()) {
    objects.remove(*iter);
}
objects.clear();
```

2

```
while (!objects.empty()) {
    delete &objects.front();
    objects.pop_front();
}
objects.clear();
```

3

```
while (!objects.empty()) {
    delete &iter;
    iter++;
}
objects.clear();
```

Are there any better approaches? Thanks

Comment: What  do you mean "I've no idea if they are correct". Check the size beforehand and the size after? Did you try printing the objects beforehand then after to see if the right one was deleted?

Comment: I don't know if the memory is being freed properly, or if there is a quicker simpler way to do it

Comment: Do you mean `std::list`? Then just `clear()`.

Comment: will that free the memory though? I've been every new needs an appropiate delete

Comment: The answer depends on exactly what `DisplayableObject` is.  A class type?  A smart pointer?  A raw pointer?

Comment: Did you use `new`? How? Please show the relevant code.

Comment: displayableojbect is a class

Comment: @thebeginner: Your list stores actual objects, not pointers to objects.  Clearing the list will automatically free the objects correctly.  You do not need to (nor should you try to) do it manually, unless you change your list to store pointers to `new`ed objects instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are conflating two different things. Let's take a `std::list` of integer pointers, and initialize them like this:

```
std::list<int *> list;

list.push_back(new int[7]);
list.push_back(new int[5]);
```

At this point, doing a

```
list.clear();
```

Will completely remove the elements in the list. However, the elements in the list are pointers to integers, which is completely separate from the actual data they're pointing to. The data is not freed. It is your responsibility to `delete[]` it beforehand:

```
for (auto &item:list)
      delete[] item;
list.clear();
```

A `std::list` is only responsible for removing the values in the list. A `std::list` has no knowledge about what a pointer, if a list contains pointers, is pointing to. For example, with the same exact list:

```
std::list<int *> list;

int a;
int b;
list.push_back(&a);
list.push_back(&b);
```

This list itself is the same exact list as the first one. It's still a list of pointers to integers. In this case,

```
list.clear();
```

Is the only thing that needs to be done here. The pointers are not pointers to `new`-ed objects. As a C++ developer, it is your responsibility to keep track of what your `new`ed, and `delete` it when it's no longer needed.

Which is why you do not want to use raw, plain, unadulterated pointers, unless it is absolutely necessary. Instead, you want to use `std::shared_ptr`, which will automatically `delete` the `new`ed objects when they are no longer needed. If, instead of

```
class SomeClass {};

std::list<SomeClass *> list;
```

you used

```
std::list<std::shared_ptr<SomeClass>> list;
```

(using a class, instead of an `int` here, for a better example); then when you

```
list.clear();
```

then if the pointed-to class members are no longer referenced by any other smart pointer, they will be automatically `delete`d.

Comment: Better to use `unique_ptr` instead of `shared_ptr` unless you actually need shared ownership — the latter incurs the overhead of maintaining a reference count.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Very helpful

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is call objects.clear(). Your list is comprised of objects (I assume DisplayableObject is simply an object and not a pointer), so each object's destructor will be called and the list will be empty.

Now, if you had stored simple pointers to the objects in your list, instead of simply storing the objects, then you would indeed need to explicitly free each element in the list prior to calling objects.clear() to clear the list of freed pointers.

Comment: Sorry I am going to delete tihs question because its stupid. Thanks for clearing that for me